# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to implement a slider on wordpress page, this error occurs only on wordpress page.

Link to Wordpress page [Link](http://208.131.135.54/~imacre17/)

Link to HTML [page](http://isotopethemes.com/slider-test/)

This is the part of code which causes the problem:

```
 n(".bg-size-cover").each(function(r, u) {
        var f = n(u),
            o = f.data("image"),
            e = null;
        if (o) return n("html").hasClass("bgsizecover") ? f.css("background-image", "url('" + o + "')") : (e = n('<img src="' + o + '"/>').css({
            height: "auto",
            width: "auto"
        }).one("load", function(n) {
            var t = n.srcElement;
            e.data("width", t.width).data("height", t.height);
            i(null)
        }), f.append(e), t.push(e)), f
    });
    n(window).on("resize", i).trigger("resize")
```

this function calculates the background size of the image, the line

```
e.data("width", t.width).data("height", t.height);
```

I've been trying to find a solution from hours, I could not, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Might be because of image not found. Check that all your images exist and that the paths are correct.

http://isotopethemes.com/App_Themes/StAndrewsLinksTrust/Images/lane-link-large.png is not found on the site you linked.

You can perform a `undefined` check on `t` before interacting with it.

```
if(typeof t !== 'undefined') e.data("width", t.width).data("height", t.height);
```

Comment: Actually, that may not be the issue, that images is not required, I forgot to remove link to it in the HTML version, I've removed the link to 'lane-link-large.png' file in the Wordpress version.

Comment: thank you for your answer though, I believe it's got something with the code.

Comment: @chandan Your WordPress site has `img` tags inside the `.bg-size-cover`, whereas the HTML site does not. This may have something to do with it. Try removing the `img`'s.

Comment: The markup may be different from what the plugin is expecting. Look at the plugin's documentation and verify your markup is the same

Comment: Great observation, I don't have it in source, it is generated by wordpress. I'll have to remove it.